# Saving current page URL to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm using a javascript step sequencer that records the current user-inputed drum pattern into the URL.

So for example before any user input the url looks like:

```
http://localhost:8888/member-index.php#/0000/0000/0000/0000/0000/0000/0000
```

and then if the user inputs a basic drum beat the URL might look like:

```
http://localhost:8888/member-index.php#/8020/0808/aaaa/0000/0000/0000/0000
```

So I want to be able to save the user-created patterns to my MySQL database so that user's can save and load beats they've previously created.

Could someone give me a quick example of what the PHP code would look like to save the pages current URL to a database?

EDIT:

People are saying to use $_GET - how would I use this with a URL like mine that is broken up into seven sections with "/" dividing them?

Comment: Why not use `$_GET` variables instead of the URL string itself?  This is the kind of thing they're designed for.

Answer (score 0):

You could use htaccess and url rewriting to redirect all requests to a specific php in which you check the url. see:[Rerouting all php requests through index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694118/rerouting-all-php-requests-through-index-php)

nevertheless I think using get/post or the request body is easier to send your data.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Use `$_GET` instead.

**Long Answer**

Retrieving the url with PHP isn't going to include what comes after the `#`, because that's only sent to the browser and not to the server.  As @Kazar says in an answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967649/get-entire-url-including-query-string-and-anchor), you could use Javascript and `document.location.hash` to retrieve the information after the hash and then send it to the server via ajax.

But fortunately there's a much better built-in solution, which is `$_GET` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)).

Instead of constructing your url thus:

```
member-index.php#/8020/0808/aaaa/0000/0000/0000/0000
```

Make it like this:

```
member-index.php?a=8020&b=0808&c=aaaa&d=0000&e=0000&f=0000&g=0000
```

Then you can retrieve this information easily in PHP:

```
$a = $_GET['a'];
$b = $_GET['b'];
...
```

And then pass it on to the database. (Even better, replace `a`, `b`, etc. with whatever the order actually means)

Comment: well if he really wants to he could use htaccess and reroute all traffic to a specific php

Comment: There are all sorts of ways he could decide to pass variables through the url string, but as far as I know this is the way it's meant to be done in php.

Comment: I figured out how to make the code appear as "http://localhost:8888/member-index.php#/a=ff00/b=0c00/c=0200/d=0000/e=0000/f=0000/g=0000" would I still be able to do it this way?

Comment: No; if you want to use `$_GET` you need to format it according to [the specifications](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).  How are you generating the url in the first place?