# AJAX, the PHP variables and me

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning how to use AJAX and I made 4 files:

> header.php
>   page1.php
>   page2.php
>   footer.php

My header contains like `body`, `html`, `head` and things. While my footer, `</body>`...
I need to make a navbar that calls page1.php trough AJAX, but what if user access page1.php directly, what happens to header and footer ;-;?
I tried to make this two things in PHP:

**header.php:**

```
<? $a = 1 ?>
```

**page1.php:**

```
<? if ($a != 1){include 'includes/header.php';} ?>
```

But page1 keeps calling header even when bloody $a IS EQUAL 1!!!!!!

I also made this in **page1.php**:

```
<? echo $a ?>
```

And guess what? Yes... it returns 1...

**AJAX code in header.php:**

```
$(function() {
            $('nav a').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var href = $(this).attr('href');

            $('#content').html('Downloading...');

            $.ajax({
                url: href,
                type: 'GET',
                error: function(){
                    // always good to have an error handler with AJAX
                },
                success: function(data){
                    $('#content').html(data);
                }
            });

                // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
                history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
                // e.preventDefault();


            });
```

HALP!

Comment: where is ajax?kindly add

Comment: 1. the question does not contain AJAX; 2. the code does not make sense.

Comment: Well, technically it is a issue caused by AJAX. Maybe there is another way to do it without all my mess...

Comment: I will add AJAX...
----------------------
AJAX code added.  
Why the code doesn't make sense, Raptor?

Comment: I suggest a fifth page that always includes the header and the footer. The `page1` and `page2` type pages would only need there own content.

Comment: I don't get it. Again, what if user try to access `page1` and `page2` directly?

Comment: @Igor [you'd use mod_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694118/rerouting-all-php-requests-through-index-php) (or similar if you're not using apache) to redirect traffic to the index page. So the user navigates to `example.com/page1.php` The server sends the request to `example.com/index.php` but with the original request as part of the query string. `index.php` see the original request was for `page1` and automatically includes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If page1.php is loaded with AJAX it can not evaluate the $a variable declared in the header.php because all PHP code in page1.php is executed serverside before the response is returned to the header page. But you can however pass a variable as a parameter along with the request in the url

```
var href = $(this).attr('href')+'?a='+'<?php echo $a; ?>';
```

This will pass a parameter with value of $a with the url like this:
//page1.php?a=1

In your page1.php you can then check if this variable is NOT passed (meaning header.php didn't request the page):

```
if (!isset($_GET['a'])){
    include 'includes/header.php';
}
```