# .htaccess redirect specific uri to diffrent php file and block access to all php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to create .htaccess file which will allow user to access files if they exists but without those with php extension.

Also I want all non file URI redirected to index.php (include all php files) but with one specific URI like

```
http://website.com/exception
http://website.com/exception/webpage.php
http://website.com/exception/webpage/all
```

I want to redirect to example.php. Both php files will be in root folder alongside .htaccess. I need your help because I've wasted couple of hours and got nothing.

EDIT: In sugested answer htaccess don't block .php files and don't redirect one specific URI (exception/...) to exception.php (not index.php).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rerouting all php requests through index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694118/rerouting-all-php-requests-through-index-php)

Comment: No, it's not. Read my edit.