# 301 old site to new with lots of url structure changes

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I will soon be 301'ing my entire site to its new home on a new domain, where it will live as a subdirectory of the main domain.  It lives at the root of its current domain.  Now, if every single old page had the exact same url structure as every single new page, the redirects are trivial. However, of the 200ish old urls that will need to be redirected, very few will exist at their new site "equivalent" (www.olddomain.com/somepage -> www.newdomain.com/olddomain/somepage) as most pages will have either a slight url change or exist somewhere else entirely, like at the root of the new site.

I'm assuming 200ish lines of specific singular 301 redirects in .htaccess would slow down the site pretty bad since .htaccess is loaded for every asset on the page, correct? As would (relatively) complex conditional logic with `mod_rewrite`?

Any ideas?

Side note: both sites, new and old, use WordPress, so if there are any WordPress-specific solutions, fire away.

Comment: It would not slow down the site using a mod_rewrite that anyone would notice. A few rules will not cause any major perfomance issues. There is more performance concerns using .htaccess in general since Apache has to scan all directories for this. Put the rewrite in your httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your traffic, if it is a personal blog, then `mod_rewrite` should be fast enough for users not to notice.

Comment: Currently, traffic peaks around 500 views/day - is that still in the acceptable range for some `mod_rewrite` logic?

Comment: Definitely, it was designed to handle as many (many more) views a second. For more insight see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145128/htaccess-mod-rewrite-performance, others